# How to retrieve the coordinates of an animated object?

Tags: unity

On Unity, I created a script in C # to animate a cube.
I am trying to create a script in C # which, once the animated object and in support of a key of the keyboard (for example F) returns to me the coordinates of the object at the moment when I pressed F

Can you give me this script?

Thank you for your help

Comment: `Transform.position` ???

Comment: We're not here to deliver scripts on demand, but we can help you solve problems you've had in trying to write the script yourself. What have you tried so far, and how do the results differ from what you want?